# SSL Pinning on iOS

Tags: ios, security, ssl, foundation

To improve my app's security and protect the user from MITM attacks I'm trying to do SSL pinning with my self-signed certificate following the content of [this post](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/03/ssl-pinning-for-increased-app-security/).

So I'm using the following code to compare the certificate that I get from the server with the one that bundled in the app.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    SecCertificateRef certificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0);
    NSData *remoteCertificateData = CFBridgingRelease(SecCertificateCopyData(certificate));
    NSLog(@"Remote Certificate Data Length: %d",[remoteCertificateData length]);
    NSString *cerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"apache" ofType:@"crt"];
    NSData *localCertData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cerPath];
    NSLog(@"Local Certificate Data Length: %d",[localCertData length]);
    if ([remoteCertificateData isEqualToData:localCertData]) {
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
    else {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

The only things that are different between my code and the one in the blog post I linked are the name and the extension (.cer to .crt) for the resource representing my certificate and the two NSLogs I added that will come handy later to show what the problem is.

In fact when this code is executed I get this output:

```
2013-05-22 16:08:53.331 HTTPS Test[5379:c07] Remote Certificate Data Length: 880
2013-05-22 16:09:01.346 HTTPS Test[5379:c07] Local Certificate Data Length: 1249
```

Obviously the comparison between the Local and the Remote certificates fails because the length of the data is different and so it also fails the pinning.

Why does this happen and how could I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you considered just saving the returned certificate data to a file and using that? Otherwise, do a diff on the data and see what's different.

Comment: No I didn't think of that! Good idea, I'll try immediately!

Comment: If you are using Alamofire then check this http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2017/07/ssl-pinning-in-ios-swift-code.html

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. The problem is probably because you have not converted your .crt file to the correct format. iOS & OSX are looking for your certificate to be in [.der](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinguished_Encoding_Rules#DER_encoding) format. You need to use [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsa.html) to convert it. [Here](https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them) is a very helpful article on this topic.  My public certificate came from an Apache server (I am assuming that yours did as well). After looking over openssl documentation I was able to figure out how to get this to work.

1) Open Terminal and change directory to the location of your .crt.

2) Execute this command:

```
openssl x509 -in your_cert.crt -outform der -out your_output_name.der
```

This will create an output file named 'your_output_file.der'. You must import this into your xCode project and reference it in the

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

method of your `NSURLConnectionDelegate` implementation.

I hope this helps!